# Problem with TypeNats vs bespoke data statement

Tags: haskell

I've been experimenting with an evalation function for a simple expression language, mainly as a way to familiarise myself with some Haskell extensions that I've not used before. The latest experiment is to use DataKinds and TypeFamilies to unify unary and binary operators. After some trouble, I made it work, but only if I represent the arity of the operators with a bespoke definition of the naturals:

```
data NatT = ZeroT | SuccT NatT
```

If I instead try to use TypeNats, the compiler fails to match the types. Below is the failing version. It's the second line of the `apply` function about which the compiler moans - the applications of `f` to `a`. The error is failure to match `Double -> FuncN (n - 1)` with `FuncN n`, (which is exactly the second line of the definition of FuncN). I can get different errors by using `n+1` and `n` in place of `n` and `n-1`. I also tried declaring FuncN to be injective, but the compiler doesn't like that either.

This problem doesn't hugley surprise me and I'm content with the working version using `NatT`, but interested to see if it is possible to work around the problem while maintaining the use of TypeNats.

```
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, GADTs, DataKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}

module FourFours
    ( NularyOp(..)
    , UnaryOp(..)
    , BinaryOp(..)
    , Term(..)
    , ListN(..)
    , eval
    ) where

import GHC.TypeNats

type family FuncN n where
    FuncN 0 = Double
    FuncN n = Double -> FuncN (n - 1)

data ListN n a where
    EmptyN :: ListN 0 a
    ConsN :: a -> ListN (n - 1) a -> ListN n a

instance Functor (ListN n) where
    fmap f EmptyN = EmptyN
    fmap f (ConsN a as) = ConsN (f a) (fmap f as)

apply :: FuncN n -> ListN n Double -> Double
apply x EmptyN = x
apply f (ConsN x xs) = apply (f x) xs

data NularyOp = Four | FortyFour | PointFour   deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)
data UnaryOp = Sqrt                            deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)
data BinaryOp = Add | Sub | Mul | Div | Pow    deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)

class Op o where
    type Arity o :: Nat
    evalOp :: o -> FuncN (Arity o)

instance Op NularyOp where
    type Arity NularyOp = 0
    evalOp Four = 4
    evalOp FortyFour = 44
    evalOp PointFour = 0.4

instance Op UnaryOp where
    type Arity UnaryOp = 1
    evalOp Sqrt = sqrt

instance Op BinaryOp where
    type Arity BinaryOp = 2
    evalOp Add = (+)
    evalOp Sub = (-)
    evalOp Mul = (*)
    evalOp Div = (/)
    evalOp Pow = (**)

data Term n where
    OpTerm :: Op o => o -> Term (Arity o)
    Apply :: Term n -> ListN n (Term 0) -> Term 0


eval :: Term n -> FuncN n
eval (OpTerm o) = evalOp o
eval (Apply o ts) = apply (eval o) (fmap eval ts)
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question is. Are you asking if it is possible to work around this TypeNats issue without a custom data type? If you just want comments on your code then perhaps other sites like https://codereview.stackexchange.com or reddit are better suited

Comment: Unfortunately it's a long standing, well known issue. There are [type checker plugins](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-natnormalise) which aim to improve this experience.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if it was possible to work around the problem while maintaining the use of TypeNats. I'll update the question to make that clear.

Comment: The first thing I'd try is adding `KnownNat (Arity o)` as a superconstraint to the `Op` class. That's probably going to cause other problems, but it should at least help with this one.

Comment: I haven't managed to exploit either of the suggestions to find a solution, but I think I now have a more detailed understanding of the problem: to type check the second clause of `apply`, the compiler would need to use the second clause of `FuncN`, but it can do so only if it can reject the first clause. At that point it has deduced `n ~ n0 + 1`, for some `n0`, but it probably doesn't have a rule that rules out `n0 + 1` being `0`. This all works when using `data NatT` in place of `Nat` because, in that case, the compiler has deduced `n ~ SuccT n` from which it can rule out `n` being `ZeroT`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve the problem. It's a bit restricted - applicable in this case only because the specific program in question makes use of only a few types within Nat. It's also inefficient. But it does at least avoid use of anything nasty like `unsafeCoerce` or `OverlappingInstances`.

The difficulty for GHC is dealing with the `FuncN` type family. To type check the right-hand side of the `ConsN` clause of the `apply` function, GHC needs to deduce `FuncN (n + 1) ~ Double -> FuncN n`. It can do so when a specific type (`0`, `1`, `2` ...) is substituted for `n`, but cannot deduce the general form with the type variable `n`.

You might consider using `FuncN (n + 1) = Double -> FuncN n` as the second clause of the definition of `FuncN`, but that is rightly not permitted because the operator `(+)` isn't a constructor: it's a type family. Even if one could do that, I don't believe it would help because GHC cannot even rule out the possibility that the first clause of `FuncN` applies to `n + 1`.

The trick that gets around this problem is to generate evidence of the type equality, in the form of the propositional equality term `FuncN (n +  1) :~: Double -> FuncN n`. We define a type alias for a function that maps a proxy for a specific type within `Nat` onto the corresponding evidence.

```
type FuncNProp n = Typeable n => Proxy n -> (FuncN (n + 1) :~: (Double -> FuncN n))
```

The `Typeable` constraint is needed so that we can use `eqT`.

I haven't found a way to construct a total function of this type, but here is one that covers just `0` and `1`, which are the only ones we need in this specific program.

```
funcNProp :: forall n . FuncNProp n
funcNProp (proxy :: Proxy n) = case eqT @n @0
                                    of Just Refl -> Refl
                                       Nothing -> case eqT @n @1
                                                       of Just Refl -> Refl
                                                          Nothing -> error "Operators with arity greater than 2 not supported"
```

The `eqT` tests allow GHC to consider just the `0` and `1` cases individually. The returned `Refl` values are the evidence, which GHC can type check because it can deduce `FuncN (n + 1) ~ Double -> FuncN n` for specific individual types within `Nat`.

We then update the second clause of apply to use this evidence

```
apply f (ConsN x (xs :: ListN n' Double)) = case funcNProp (Proxy :: Proxy n' ) of Refl -> apply (f x) xs
```

... in the `ConsN` pattern clause, we also match `n'` to the type. With that type, we construct a proxy to pass to `funcNProp`, which generates the evidence needed to typecheck `apply (f x) xs`.

Here's the complete program:

```
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances
          , GADTs
          , DataKinds
          , TypeFamilies
          , TypeOperators
          , UndecidableInstances
          , ScopedTypeVariables
          , RankNTypes
          , TypeApplications
          , FlexibleContexts #-}

module FourFours
    ( NularyOp(..)
    , UnaryOp(..)
    , BinaryOp(..)
    , Term(..)
    , ListN(..)
    , eval
    ) where

import GHC.TypeNats ( Nat, type (+), type (-) )
import Data.Typeable ( Typeable, Proxy(..), type (:~:)(..), eqT )

type family FuncN n where
    FuncN 0 = Double
    FuncN n = Double -> FuncN (n - 1)

data ListN n a where
    EmptyN :: ListN 0 a
    ConsN :: Typeable n => a -> ListN n a -> ListN (n + 1) a

instance Functor (ListN n) where
    fmap f EmptyN = EmptyN
    fmap f (ConsN a as) = ConsN (f a) (fmap f as)

type FuncNProp n = Typeable n => Proxy n -> (FuncN (n + 1) :~: (Double -> FuncN n))

funcNProp :: forall n . FuncNProp n
funcNProp (proxy :: Proxy n) = case eqT @n @0
                                    of Just Refl -> Refl
                                       Nothing -> case eqT @n @1
                                                       of Just Refl -> Refl
                                                          Nothing -> error "Operators with arity greater than 2 not supported"

apply :: forall n . FuncN n -> ListN n Double -> Double
apply x EmptyN = x
apply f (ConsN x (xs :: ListN n' Double)) = case funcNProp (Proxy :: Proxy n' ) of Refl -> apply (f x) xs

data NularyOp = Four | FortyFour | PointFour   deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)
data UnaryOp = Sqrt                            deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)
data BinaryOp = Add | Sub | Mul | Div | Pow    deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)

class Op o where
    type Arity o :: Nat
    evalOp :: o -> FuncN (Arity o)

instance Op NularyOp where
    type Arity NularyOp = 0
    evalOp Four = 4
    evalOp FortyFour = 44
    evalOp PointFour = 0.4

instance Op UnaryOp where
    type Arity UnaryOp = 1
    evalOp Sqrt = sqrt

instance Op BinaryOp where
    type Arity BinaryOp = 2
    evalOp Add = (+)
    evalOp Sub = (-)
    evalOp Mul = (*)
    evalOp Div = (/)
    evalOp Pow = (**)

data Term n where
    OpTerm :: Op o => o -> Term (Arity o)
    Apply :: Term n -> ListN n (Term 0) -> Term 0


eval :: Term n -> FuncN n
eval (OpTerm o) = evalOp o
eval (Apply o ts) = apply (eval o) (fmap eval ts)
```

Comment: Actually, if you accept use of `unsafeCoerce`, then the definition `funcNProp _ = unsafeCoerce Refl` is simpler, unrestricted and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is another solution that involves adding just one carefully placed constraint.

As mentioned in the previous answer, the difficulty for GHC is dealing with the `FuncN` type family. To type check the right-hand side of the `ConsN` clause of the `apply` function, GHC needs to deduce `FuncN (n + 1) ~ Double -> FuncN n`. It can do so when a specific type (`0`, `1`, `2` ...) is substituted for `n`, but cannot deduce the general form with the type variable `n`.

The solution is to add that constraint to the `ConsN` clause of the `ListN` data definition. That is, in effect, a promise only to construct lists that satisfy the
property. Since the property is a tautology, that isn't a restriction but, what's more, GHC is able to establish the property provided all `ListN` constructions are literal (so that the TypeNat is a specific instance), which is the case for this specific program.

The whole program:

```
{-#LANGUAGE GADTs
          , DataKinds
          , TypeFamilies
          , TypeOperators
          , UndecidableInstances #-}

module Main where

import GHC.TypeNats ( Nat, type (+), type (-) )

type family FuncN n where
    FuncN 0 = Double
    FuncN n = Double -> FuncN (n - 1)

data ListN n a where
    EmptyN :: ListN 0 a
    ConsN :: FuncN (n + 1) ~ (Double -> FuncN n) => a -> ListN n a -> ListN (n + 1) a

instance Functor (ListN n) where
    fmap f EmptyN = EmptyN
    fmap f (ConsN a as) = ConsN (f a) (fmap f as)

apply :: FuncN n -> ListN n Double -> Double
apply x EmptyN = x
apply f (ConsN x xs) = apply (f x) xs

data NularyOp = Four | FortyFour | PointFour   deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)
data UnaryOp = Sqrt                            deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)
data BinaryOp = Add | Sub | Mul | Div | Pow    deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)

class Op o where
    type Arity o :: Nat
    evalOp :: o -> FuncN (Arity o)

instance Op NularyOp where
    type Arity NularyOp = 0
    evalOp Four = 4
    evalOp FortyFour = 44
    evalOp PointFour = 0.4

instance Op UnaryOp where
    type Arity UnaryOp = 1
    evalOp Sqrt = sqrt

instance Op BinaryOp where
    type Arity BinaryOp = 2
    evalOp Add = (+)
    evalOp Sub = (-)
    evalOp Mul = (*)
    evalOp Div = (/)
    evalOp Pow = (**)

data Term n where
    OpTerm :: Op o => o -> Term (Arity o)
    Apply :: Term n -> ListN n (Term 0) -> Term 0


eval :: Term n -> FuncN n
eval (OpTerm o) = evalOp o
eval (Apply o ts) = apply (eval o) (fmap eval ts)


main :: IO ()
main = let subterm = Apply (OpTerm Sqrt) (ConsN (OpTerm Four) EmptyN)
           term = Apply (OpTerm Add) (ConsN subterm (ConsN (OpTerm Four) EmptyN))
       in print $ eval term
```